# Artifactory Cocoapods - Getting TypeError - no implicit conversion of Pathname into String

Tags: ios, cocoapods, artifactory

I am trying to get Cocoapods (local) work with artifactory. Below are the steps I have done.

1. Created ***Cocoapods-local*** - repo
2. Deployed ***'mypod.tar.gz'*** to local instance of jfrog artifactory pro.
3. Changed pod file.

   ```
   use_frameworks!

   ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

   plugin 'cocoapods-art', :sources => [
                   'cocoapods-local'
   ]

   target 'Download Sample' do
        pod 'dowloadHud'
   target 'Download SampleTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
   end
   target 'Download SampleUITests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
   end
   end
   ```

   4. When I running pod install, I am getting below error.

   > [!]Error installing dowloadHud

   ```
   TypeError - no implicit conversion of Pathname into String
   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:513:in `initialize'
   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:513:in `exception'
   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:513:in `raise'
   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:513:in `block in mv'
   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1558:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1567:in `block in fu_each_src_dest0'
   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1565:in `each'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/JFrogDev/cocoapods-art/issues/11) for this, you can upvote and provide your usecase there to help the developers solve it quickly.